# How to group types with StructureMap?

Tags: ioc-container, structuremap

I have some classes

```
public interface IProvider
{
    void Load(int id);
}
public class Provider1 : IProvider
{
     public void Load(int id) {} 
}
public class Provider2 : IProvider
{
    public void Load(int id) {}
} 
public interface IService
{
    void Load(int id);
}
public class Service : IService
{
    IProvider provider;
    public Service(IProvider provider) { this.provider=provider; }
    public void Load(int id) { provider.Load(id); }
}
```

and I registered them with StructureMap like this:

```
For<IService>().Use<Service>().Named("core"); 
For<IProvider>().Use<Provider1>().Named("core"); 
For<IService>().Use<Service>().Named("gen"); 
For<IProvider>().Use<Provider2>().Named("gen");
```

but when I try to get Service by

```
var service1 = ObjectFactory.GetNamedInstance<IService>("core"); 
var service2 = ObjectFactory.GetNamedInstance<IService>("gen");
```

so in both cases IProvider instanciated to Provider2, why?

I expected for 1st case the IProvider will instanciate to Provider1 
       and for 2nd case to Provider2

So, how I need to register them in order to get what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not telling structuremap what dependencies the different instances of Service are having. In order to tell, use the [Ctor method](http://www.theabsentmindedcoder.com/2010/05/structure-map-26-constructor-arguments.html) that indicate what arguments should be passed when creating an instance.

```
For<IProvider>().Add<Provider1>().Named("core");
For<IProvider>().Add<Provider2>().Named("gen");
For<IService>().Add<Service>()
    .Ctor<IProvider>("provider").Is(c => c.GetInstance<IProvider>("core"))
    .Named("coreService");
For<IService>().Add<Service>()
    .Ctor<IProvider>("provider").Is(c => c.GetInstance<IProvider>("gen"))
    .Named("genService");
```

Note the use of Add instead of Use. The add indicates that we are adding a new instance, use indicates that a instance should be default. So if you want to be able to have core as default you can register as follows:

```
For<IProvider>().Use<Provider1>();
For<IProvider>().Add<Provider2>().Named("gen");
For<IService>().Use<Service>();
For<IService>().Add<Service>()
    .Ctor<IProvider>("provider").Is(c => c.GetInstance<IProvider>("gen"))
    .Named("genService");
```

and resolve the instances like this:

```
var score = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IService>();
var sgen = ObjectFactory.GetNamedInstance<IService>("genService");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try telling structuremap what instance of IProvider you want for service1 with the name like this:

```
For<IService>().Use<Service>().Named("core").Ctor<IProvider>().Is(y => y.GetInstance<IProvider>("core"));
```